# insert a line at the top and other at the bottom of the file when first line match with sed

Tags: awk, sed

I want to insert a line at the top and other at the bottom of the file when the first line matches a string with sed. I tried the line below without success and variations of it. It inserts the first line but not the last line:

file.txt

```
REMARK
Blah
Blah
blah
```

Sed:

```
sed -e '1!b;/REMARK/i MODEL 1' -e '$ a ENDMODEL ' file.txt
```

Thanks
Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed, It seem you get gnu sed.

```
sed -i -e '1{/REMARK/{i MODEL' -e ':A;$a ENDMODEL' -e 'n;bA}}' file.txt
```

Comment: Hi ctac_,  the second time over the file still adds at the end and only must do it when the first line matches REMARK. I do not understand it to see what is wrong.

Comment: You are right, with -i option the second time and so on ENDMODEL is add, I update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you. Following will insert a string `MODEL` after match of first line which is having string `REMARK` in it. Also inserts string `ENDMODEL` after the last line read.

```
awk 'FNR==1 && $0=="REMARKS"{print $0 ORS "MODEL";next} 1; END{print "ENDMODEL"}'  Input_file
```

In case you need to change Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above command too.

***EDIT:*** OP says last line should be added only when first line match is found then following may help.

```
awk 'FNR==1 && $0=="REMARK"{flag=1;print "MODEL" ORS $0;next} 1; END{if(flag){print "ENDMODEL"}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: No, it is not helping. I looking to insert and add only if the first line match "REMARKS". Thanks

Comment: @MarioABianchet, ok I had written `REMARK` which I changed to `REMARKS` kindly check and let me know then?

Comment: Append the last line but not the first. and does it independently of the first line have or not the string.

Comment: @MarioABianchet, yes it should work like that only, could you check once and let me know then the same?

Comment: Only added at the end and independently of the match. But, I asking to insert in the top and append in the bottom only if the original file start with REMARK

Comment: @MarioABianchet, please check my EDIT code now and let me know if that helps?

Comment: It is work, thanks. I will look, but if  you know have to make that any portion of the string match REMARK, i'll appreciate it.

Comment: @MarioABianchet, Could you please do lemme know the reason for removing this answer as correct one?

Comment: Certainly, both are correct but I asked at the time for a ```sed``` approach and to be just  @ctac_  answer was a sed script and your awk script... However, both answers teached me a lot at the time thanks. I hope did not offend you and apologize if did.

Comment: @MarioABianchet, No offense and all buddy, you selected an answer as correct which you think it is, no issues with it, just wanted to know the reason :) cheers.